# A way to display a DropBox file in a web app

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api, embedding, dropbox-sdk

I know there is a way to embed previews using Dropbox Embedding, but this doesnt seem to work for me at all.

The documentation I am referring to is this: [Using the Embedder](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/embedder)

The anchor tag is simply rendered, and clicking on it will direct me to the dropbox preview content itself.

What I am looking for is the dropbox preview to be rendered without any user interaction/clicking on it.

Has anybody been able to achieve this?

Comment: The Dropbox Embedder is designed to work without user interaction. If that's not working for you, it sounds like something went wrong setting it up. Did you follow the instructions on that page? For instance, did you successfully include the dropins.js script as instructed there?

Comment: Yes. i followed that document line by line. I am wondering if I need to have DropBox Business API?

Comment: No, the Dropbox Business API is not required to use the Dropbox Embedder. I suggest opening a new question or contacting [Dropbox developer support](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/support) with the technical details of the issue you're seeing. For instance, show exactly what code you're using, and what, if any, error(s) you get in the browser console when the page is loading.